# Python merge 2 lists

Tags: python, list

```
pricelist=[373, 381, 398, 402, 404, 457, 535, 550, 566]
pricelist2=[97, 00, 98, 98, 98, 97, 99, 97, 98]
```

I would like to merge these 2 lists (strings) into the following :

`final_price=[373.97, 381.00, 398.98]` etc

So join the prices together and add a dot. Pls help

EDIT, Sorry I forgot to mention that the lists are currently strings

Comment: `[round(i + j / 100, 2) for i, j in zip(pricelist, pricelist2)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a list comprehension:

```
pricelist=[373, 381, 398, 402, 404, 457, 535, 550, 566]
pricelist2=[97, 0, 98, 98, 98, 97, 99, 97, 98]

out = [a+b/100 for a,b in zip(pricelist, pricelist2)]
```

output:

```
[373.97, 381.0, 398.98, 402.98, 404.98, 457.97, 535.99, 550.97, 566.98]
```

NB. as pointed out by @OlvinRoght if you plan to use the **representation** of the output number, better [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to avoid floating point precision issues (for example `6+94/100` would give `6.9399999999999995`)

```
out = [round(a+b/100, 2) for a,b in zip(pricelist, pricelist2)]
```

##### numpy

You might also be interested in using a specialized library. [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) can handle arrays/vectors very efficiently:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array(pricelist)
a2 = np.array(pricelist2)

out = a1+a2/100
```

output:

```
array([373.97, 381.  , 398.98, 402.98, 404.98, 457.97, 535.99, 550.97,
       566.98])
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght I added a rounding, but I feel that OP should rather use strings if display is really the goal ;)

Comment: Else, one could use `out = [f'{a}.{b:02}' for a,b in zip(pricelist, pricelist2)]`

Comment: Indeed. but I prefer to cut this float "tail" anyway if constructing number. We can't predict further workflow, but maybe next question from this author will be *"why am I getting `7.039999999999999` when add `1.1` to `5.94`?"*

Comment: I forgot to mention that the current lists are strings

Comment: @Singh then use `out = [f'{a}.{b}' for a,b in zip(pricelist, pricelist2)]`

Comment: @Singh, or functional approach `out = list(map(".".join, zip(pricelist, pricelist2)))`

Comment: I hope I can send it here, I would like to insert this list into my database, but my for loop in zip is not working. Any suggestions

Comment: Yes, start a new question with all the details (after ensuring this is not already answered)